# How to erase certain lines from 10000 files efficiently

Tags: command-line, bash

I have `10000` files in a directory. I would like to erase lines so that I keep 2 lines in the header, 2 lines at the tail, and every 100th line in the middle.

For instance:

```
#header1
#header2
0     x y
1     x y
...
100   x y
101   x y
...
80000 x y
#tail1
#tail2
```

should become

```
#header1
#header2
0     x y
100   x y
200   x y
...
80000 x y
#tail1
#tail2
```

What is the most efficient and easy way to do this? I have around 20 directories with 10000 such files of varying length that I have to truncate.

Comment: opposed to awk? I suspect it or another language may be easiest

Answer (score 0):

As commented, awk is a good choice for this. If it's a one time task, I would not bother more than creating an awk-based script that writes the shrunken file from the complete one taken from its parameter and calling it from a find ... -exec ... command.
Like

```
cat $HOME/bin/shrinkit.sh
#!/bin/sh

awk '/^#/ && headcnt<2  {print; ++headcnt}; $1~/^[0-9]+$/ { if(!(cnt%100)) {print}; ++cnt}; cnt && /^#/ && tailcnt<2  {print; ++tailcnt}' "$1" >"$1.tmp"  && mv "$1.tmp" "$1"


cd $workdir
find . -type f -exec $HOME/bin/shrinkit.sh {} \;
```

Comment: If you wish to avoid awk just for theory's sake, then the question is less about doing something in practice, and more about programming style, in which case StackOverflow or Programmers.SE might be better boards.  This is a good answer for SuperUser.  Practical, works.  sodiumnitrate should accept it, unless a better answer comes, unless he cannot use awk, in which case the question should be updated to specify that.